# symfony: Impersonate a User In multiple Firewalls

Tags: symfony

I have two firewalls for admin and my users.
I want switch user from admin to another users:

```
    admin:
        pattern: /admin
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        switch_user:
            role: ROLE_ADMIN
        logout:
            path:   /admin/logout
            target: /

    user:
        pattern: /user
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        logout:
            path:   /user/logout
            target: /
```

When i login by admin, I can switch just on admins but not users.

Comment: refer this http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html

Comment: @Robert this only for one special firewall

Answer (score 1):

Both of your firewalls have to be under the same [context](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#reference-security-firewall-context).

Try this:

```
admin:
    context: broadcast
    pattern: /admin
    anonymous: ~
    http_basic: ~
    switch_user:
        role: ROLE_ADMIN
    logout:
        path:   /admin/logout
        target: /

user:
    context: broadcast
    pattern: /user
    anonymous: ~
    http_basic: ~
    logout:
        path:   /user/logout
        target: /
```

Comment: my user and admin can has same username and another informations. user and admin completely are separate

Comment: Did you try ?
If you are on an admin page and try to impesonate an user on /user/[RANDOMUSERPAGE], it will chose the user firewall and retrieve a user (even if an admin has the same username).

Comment: when i switch for user that give me: "Expression "has_role('ROLE_USER')" denied access"

Comment: I also tried but I had the same problem "denied access". Even when using the root of the destination path I want to impersonate (which doesn't need the user to be logged). I think the access is denied because the `ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH` is not found in this context.